# Regex for paragraph numbering in C#

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I am looking for Regex expression that will match any of the following:

```
1.0
2.0
3.1
4.2.1
2.1.1.7
1.3.17.11
12.23.54.18
```

the nesting/level could be higher than 4 levels...the digits between the dots likely not to exceed 2 digits (last sample).

I tried this `@"\d.\d+"` but in some cases it did not work.

I am also looking for expression that will match ONLY this:

```
1.0
12.0
4.0
```

Here also - no more than 2 digits before the dot.

Comment: Try `@"(?m)^\d+(?:\.\d+)+"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, think about the structure of what you want to match:

A single digit:

```
\d
```

A single number of arbitrary length:

```
\d+
```

A single number, constrained to at most 2 digits:

```
\d{1,2}
```

A number, followed by a dot, followed by another number:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

A number, followed by a dot, followed by another number, followed by another dot, followed by yet another number:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

Notice a pattern? Exactly, you can use grouping and repetition to match that pattern to an arbitrary length:

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})+
```

Note that `.` is a meta-character in regular expressions, matching (almost) any character, so to match a literal dot, you need to escape it (as shown above).

To match just two levels of nesting you can constrain the `*` after the parentheses in a similar manner:

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2}){1}
```

This means it will have to match *exactly* once. However, in that case you can also simplify to a regex we've seen before:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
```

However, putting an exact number of repetitions at the end can be helpful, if you want to create regexes that match *n* levels of nesting, for arbitrary *n*.

Comment: looking at this: \d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})*
Doesn't mean that it will match \d(1,2) zero or more times?
So will this match all the items in the first group that I specified?

Comment: I've corrected it by now. It now uses `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
(\d{1,2}[.])+\d{1,2}
```

Comment: Why the excessive character classes and quantifiers? Is `(\d{1,2}[.])*\d{1,2}` not simple enough?

Comment: Jupp, I guess you are right. Changed that in my answer.